# When is bash launched and by what parent process (at startup and at opening a new terminal)

Tags: bash, shell, arch-linux, terminal

I seek two answers to this question:

In systems like Arch Linux, that come without a WM by default, what process launches the login shell?

Then, what launches new shells when:

1. I press alt+f2 (when the WM is not enabled)
2. OR when I simply open another tab in Terminal emulator (Terminator et al)

I can't seem to find a simple answer for this, as I hazard a guess: there isn't one.

Comment: If you press capital V in `top` to get a tree view of your active processes, you see that your shell is started by your terminal emulator or `login` if you are using the [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). Both of them are in turn started by Systemd, the default init system in Arch Linux.

Comment: How brilliant, thank you! I did not stop to think that systemd handled this but then of course it does.